# JWT compliant implementation for Python

Tags: python, jwt

I have no much experience with JSON Web Tokens ([RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)). But I have to admiit this is frustrating.

All Python implementations listed at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) produce invalid tokens according their online validator.

Does anybody know a compliant JWT implementation for Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I [reported to the project](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt/issues/227#issuecomment-258797522), [pyjwt](https://github.com/jpadilla/pyjwt) doesn't correctly handle secrets **already** base64-encoded.